# Android: IntentService suddenly stops

Tags: android, intentservice, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am developing a tracking application in android.

While I tested the application I found a problem:

I'm using AlarmManager to start a WakefulBroadcast that calls an IntentService, inside the OnHandleIntent method I'm calling requestLocationUpdates() from FusedLocation, and starting a Handler/CountDownTimer to removeLocationUpdates

The problem is that sometimes the service suddenly stops, without warning or explanation.

And the log stops showing the locationUpdate working or the CountDownTimer executed

Can someone help me know why my IntentService is stopping suddenly? or is there another way to keep the service executing/alive while receiving the locationUpdates?

ServiceManager:

```
public void StartExecuteSubscriptionService(long nextTimeMillis){
    Intent intent = new Intent(contextWeakReference.get(),ExecSubscriptionWakefulBroadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(contextWeakReference.get(),
            Constants.EXEC_SUBSCRIPTIONS_SERVICE_REQUESTCODE,
            intent, 0);


    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) contextWeakReference.get().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTimeInmillis, pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT  && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTimeInmillis, pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTimeInmillis, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

WakefulBroadcast:

```
public class ExecSubscriptionWakefulBroadcast extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, ExecSubscriptionsService.class);
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(context,new Exception("Ejecutando ExecSubscriptionWakefulBroadcast "+ TelephonyUtils.getSystemDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    startWakefulService(context, service);
}
```

}

ExecSuscriptionService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(this,new Exception("Ejecutando ExecSubscriptionService "+TelephonyUtils.getSystemDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));

        try{
            LocationUpdateRequester locationUpdateRequester = new LocationUpdateRequester(this.getApplicationContext(),intent);
            locationUpdateRequester.requestLocationUpdates();
        }catch (Exception e){
            CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(this,e);
        }
}
```

LocationUpdateRequester:

```
public void requestLocationUpdates() throws SecurityException {
    try{
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }catch (Exception e){
        CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) throws SecurityException {
    try{
        CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),new Exception("Conectado a GoogleServices "+TelephonyUtils.getSystemDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));


        CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),new Exception("Iniciando la busqueda "+TelephonyUtils.getSystemDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, TelephonyUtils.createLocationRequest(),listener);

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Constants.TIMEOUT_GPS,20000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),new Exception("Servicio "+ejecucionId+" encendido y ejecutando"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),new Exception("Ejecutando CountDown "+TelephonyUtils.getSystemDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,listener);
                googleApiClient.disconnect();
                releaseWake();

            }
        }.start();           

    }catch (Exception e){
        CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),e);
        releaseWake();
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            CatchExceptionsUtils.saveException(contextWeakReference.get(),new Exception("Guardando registro; " +location.getAccuracy()+" "+location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude()+" "+TelephonyUtils.getSystemDate("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")+" "+ejecucionId));

            locationList.add(location);
        }
    }
};
```

---

18  Ejecutando ExecSubscriptionWakefulBroadcast 2017-05-29 15:11:14 2017-05-29 15:11:13.000

18  Ejecutando ExecSubscriptionService 2017-05-29 15:11:15  2017-05-29 15:11:13.000

18  Próxima suscripcion inicia en: 0 minutos    2017-05-29 15:11:14.000

18  Conectando a GoogleServices 2017-05-29 15:11:15 2017-05-29 15:11:14.000

18  Conectado a GoogleServices 2017-05-29 15:11:15  2017-05-29 15:11:14.000

18  Iniciando la busqueda 2017-05-29 15:11:16   2017-05-29 15:11:14.000

18  Busqueda iniciada 2017-05-29 15:11:16   2017-05-29 15:11:14.000

18  Servicio 1496088675756 encendido y ejecutando   2017-05-29 15:11:14.000

18  Guardando registro; 2017/05/29 15:11:17 1496088675756   2017-05-29 
15:11:15.000

18  Guardando registro; 2017/05/29 15:11:32 1496088675756   2017-05-29 
15:11:31.000

18  Servicio 1496088675756 encendido y ejecutando   **2017-05-29 15:11:34.000**

18  Ejecutando ExecSubscriptionService 2017-05-29 15:26:17  **2017-05-29 15:26:16.000**

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a suitable use of `IntentService`. Once `onHandleIntent()` ends, your `IntentService` is destroyed. Your process can be terminated at any point thereafter.

Replace the `IntentService` with a regular `Service`, kicking off your work in `onStartCommand()`. Call `stopSelf()` when you are done with the service.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I thought that the Handler will do the trick of keeping the "one shot", I changed my IntentService to a Service and it worked perfectly :D